# Updating the 'items' option for sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using sortable as below :

```
    $('.column').sortable({
        connectWith: "#column1",
        revert: 100,
        items: ".myItems:not(.excluded)",
}).disableSelection();
```

Is it possible to update the `items:` callback on the fly?

So if a particular condition occurs `items:` becomes items: `.myItems` instead of `.myItems:not(.excluded)`.

Comment: As far as I remember, calling sortable({...}) again overrides previous settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set new options by calling sortable() again:

```
$('.column').sortable('option', 'items', '.myItems')
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-option